# Loading template in a form grails

Tags: ajax, grails, visibility, textfield, readonly

I want to create a form that has fields (phone, email, password), see exact layout [here](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8293/7607547016_ca8f5a8459.jpg). The form should display all as labels unless edit btn is clicked, then label will become textbox. Since grails button has no visibility/read only property I opted for remoteaction button. 
My prob is I can't seem to display all with in the form including the template I made (no unless I click edit btn, that is the time the label/text field shows) but not on first load.

templates:
Email:

```
    <g:if test="${!isEditEmail}">
              <td id="email">${profileInstance?.email}</td></g:if>
        <g:else>
            <td><g:textField name="emailTxt" value="${profileInstance?.email}" />
  </td></g:else>
```

Phone

```
    <g:if test="${!isEditPhone}">
              <td id="email">${profileInstance?.phone}</td></g:if>
        <g:else>
            <td><g:textField name="emailTxt" value="${profileInstance?.phone}" />
            </td></g:else>
```

Snippet code from My GSP called "profile" for Phone:

```
    <th scope="row"><label for="profileEditPhone">Phone:</label></th>

     <td id="showPhoneText"></td>

    <td><g:actionSubmit id="btnEditPhone"  action="setPhoneTxtAreaVisible" update="showPhoneText" value="${message(code: 'default.button.edit.label', default: 'Edit')}" /></td>

  </tr>
```

here is my code:

```
def setPhoneTxtAreaVisible=
    {
        def employeeId= params.employeeId

        MySession session = MySession.getMySession(request, params.employeeId)
        isEditPhone=true
        profileInstance = session.profileInstance

        render(template:"/layouts/phoneProfile", model:[profileInstance:session.profileInstance, isEditPhone:true])


    }
```

this is working great but the output is the  `<td id="showPhoneText"></td>` has no value or display in the GSP (profile) unless I click the button "btnEditPhone".

So I changed my code to:

```
def profile=
    {
        def employeeId= params.employeeId


    MySession session = MySession.getMySession(request, employeeId)

    //findAllByCmCaseIdCmCase
    def employee = Employee.get(employeeId as Long)
    def empUser = EmployeeUser.findByEmployeeIdEmployee(employee)
    profileInstance = new Profile();
    profileInstance.id=employeeId as Long
    profileInstance.userName  = empUser.useridUsers.username
    profileInstance.password = empUser.useridUsers.passwordText
    profileInstance.email = employee.emplEmailAddr
    profileInstance.employeeName = employee.formatFirstLastName()
    profileInstance.phone = employee.formattedEmplWorkTelNbr()
    session.profileInstance = profileInstance

    if(profileInstance)
    {

        render(template:"/layouts/phoneProfile", model:[profileInstance:session.profileInstance, isEditPhone:false])
    }

    return [profileInstance: profileInstance, mySession: session, isEditEmail:false]
}
```

-not working great, only renders the phone template.

So I changed my html code to this instead of using update

```
<tr>
        <th scope="row"><label for="profileEditPhone">Phone:</label></th>
           <td ><g:render template="/layouts/phoneProfile" /></td>

        <td> <g:submitToRemote action="setPhoneTxtAreaVisible" value="${message(code: 'default.button.edit.label', default: 'Edit')}"  /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>

      </tr>
```

- not working as I want.

Question: How do I display the Profile page, with all the templates already there on FIRST LOAD without me having to click edit btn?

Comment: The link of *see exact layout here* does not work ...

Comment: this is the imaghe link http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8293/7607547016_ca8f5a8459.jpg

Comment: The image is still not available. Did you find a solution for this issue? If so, please post it and include the image link in the question itself by editing it.